# Using datepicker with dd/mm/yyyy format

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the ng-bootstrap datepicker, and I'd like to know how can I set the model like dd/mm/yyyy? For default, when the user select one day, a date like mm/dd/yyyy is sent to the model. Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: If you have a look here: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api there's a NgbDateParserFormatter that you can use. Example here: https://gist.github.com/nrobinaubertin/61ff1c3db355c74f4e56f485b566ab22

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<input type="date" name="Date" class="form-control" [ngModel]="mydate | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'" (ngModelChange)="mydate=$event" [value]="mydate | date:'dd/mm/yyyy'" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) fb: FormBuilder, private datePipe: DatePipe) {}

...

this.datePipe.transform(createdDate, 'dd-MMM-yyyy')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it